# Cassandra ALTER TABLE DROP column fails with not found in table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra table with an empty column of type TEXT that appears in DESCRIBE TABLE but not in SELECT column FROM table, ALTER TABLE table DROP column, or ALTER TABLE table RENAME column TO new_column.
How can I drop this column without losing any data?

This is a 3-node cluster.  No errors are logged in /var/log/cassandra/system.log, cassandra.log or debug.log.

Neither nodetool upgradesstables and nodetool repair reported any errors.  Each was executed on all 3 nodes of the cluster.

```
$ cqlsh 192.168.1.1 9042
Connected to my_laptop at 192.168.1.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]


CREATE TABLE proj.stuff (
    my_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    her_id uuid,
    her_name text,
    my_odd_column text,
    status boolean
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = 'Stores Initiative Entity for MyProject'
    AND compaction = {'class':     
'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',   
'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 
'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

cqlsh:proj> ALTER TABLE stuff RENAME my_odd_column TO old_my_odd_column;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot     
rename unknown column my_odd_column in keyspace stuff"
```

NOTE: the keyspace name is wrong in error message, it is actually the table name

```
cqlsh:proj> ALTER TABLE stuff DROP my_odd_column;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Column    
my_odd_column was not found in table stuff"

cqlsh:proj> SELECT my_id, my_odd_column FROM stuff;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]         
message="Undefined name my_odd_column in selection clause"
```

Comment: same problem here. Can't DROP column either:

Comment: isn't _keyspace_ and _table_ the same thing?